cast_overflow and overflow_assign
I am getting a cast_overflow error that I do not understand.  Here is the code:
u16 b;
u16 a;

a=b+1;

a=(a>9)?(a-10):(a)

Here is the error message:

cast_overflow : Truncation due to cast operation on (a>9)?a-10:a from 32 to 16 bits.
overflow_assign: a is assigned from (a>9)?(a-10):a.

All the variables are type u16.

If the values are smaller than int they are promoted before computations. So a-10 would be an int.

I'm unsure what C implementation you are using, but part of your confusion may arise from the fact that its diagnostics use the word "cast" where "conversion" would be more correct.  A "cast" involves a typecast operator, and its effect is a (possibly trivial) value conversion.  But there are cases where conversions are performed without a cast, such as in assignment statements.

Note also that your code is not erroneous as far as the C language is concerned (provided that there is a suitable in-scope definition for nonstandard type u16), and that I see no reason to fear any unexpected behavior from it.  You should be able to satisfy the compiler that you know what you are doing by putting in an explicit cast: a = (u16) ((a > 9) ? (a - 10) : a).

"cast_overflow : Truncation due to cast operation on (a>9)?a-10:a from 32 to 16 bits."  This is gibberish. What tool gave you such a nonsense error message? You'd think those who make C compilers would know of the correct C language terminology...

@BoP And more subtly: the 3rd operand a gets silently promoted to int too, because the ?: operator uses the "usual arithmetic conversions" between the 2nd and 3rd operand no matter which one that is evaluated.

@Rahul K V, instead of 1,9,10, stay with unsigned math and use 1u, 9u, 10u.  If that does not fix things, use a cast a=... -> a=(u16)(...);
